# Pandas - DataFrame - finding rows with the two latest date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
|  No   |   Date     |   hours  |    Flag   |
|:------|:-----------|:---------|:----------|
|  101  | 13.01.2021 |   2:45   |     0     |
|  101  | 13.01.2021 |   1:20   |     0     |
|  101  | 15.02.2021 |   3:15   |     0     |
|  101  | 16.02.2021 |   0:30   |     0     |
|  101  | 02.03.2021 |   1:20   |     0     |
|  101  | 02.03.2021 |   2:40   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   2:05   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   1:45   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   1:25   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   0:45   |     0     |
```

Then I want to extract all rows with the two latest dates. Alternativ with the latest date, the three latest dates etc.
A dataframe (with the two latest dates) like this should be the target:

```
|  No   |   Date     |   hours  |    Flag   |
|:------|:-----------|:---------|:----------|
|  101  | 02.03.2021 |   1:20   |     0     |
|  101  | 02.03.2021 |   2:40   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   2:05   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   1:45   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   1:25   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   0:45   |     0     |
```

I tried:

```
df.nlargest(2, 'Date', keep='all')
```

this produces sth. like this:

```
|  No   |   Date     |   hours  |    Flag   |
|:------|:-----------|:---------|:----------|
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   2:05   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   1:45   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   1:25   |     0     |
|  101  | 19.06.2021 |   0:45   |     0     |
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Filter 2 largest Datetimes  by [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and then filter all `Date`s which match by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df[df['Date'].isin(df['Date'].nlargest(2))]

print (df)
    No       Date hours  Flag
6  101 2021-06-19  2:05     0
7  101 2021-06-19  1:45     0
8  101 2021-06-19  1:25     0
9  101 2021-06-19  0:45     0
```

Comment: a nitpick, but nlargest would scale better than a sort + tail(2)